# Upgrading from Visual Studio 2005 Team Suite to Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, visual-studio-2010, upgrade

What are the steps I should do and everything I should consider when upgrading from Visual Studio 2005 Team Suite to Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate?

Where can things go wrong?

Consider the fact I'm using TFS 2008 and have Continuous Integration and Nightly Builds on build machines.

Answer (score 0):

One big Problem are Unittests with autocreated Private Accessors. If you want to touch them you have to rewrite them...

The issue is described [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469632/unit-test-with-accessors)